# Django - Object list inside object list

Tags: django, database, listview

I'm using Django to render a list of tube numbers with their attached ingredient. When clicking on a tube number it renders the list of all the ingredients. Then if I click on an ingredient I want it to replace the saved ingredient for this tube.
But I don't know how to proceed, if I should do a sub-app for ingredients in my tube app, or if their is a way to keep the tube id.

I tried many things, here is my actual views :

```
def tube_view(request):
    tubes = Tube.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tube_ing.html', {'tubes': tubes})

def tube_detail_view(request, my_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Tube, id=my_id)
    request.session['my_id'] = my_id
    ings = Ing.objects.all()
    return render(request, "tube_detail.html", {"obj": obj, "ings": ings)

def tube_choice(request, id_ing):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Ing, id=id_ing)
    request.session['id_ing'] = id_ing
    data = {'qty': 100}
    form = TubeForm(data)
    return render(request, "tube_choice.html", {"obj": obj, 'form': form})

def tube_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TubeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            id_ing = request.session['id_ing']
            form.cleaned_data['name_ing'] = my_id
            t = Tube(name_ing_tube=name_ing_ing)
            t.save()
        else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tube_ing/')
    else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/tube_ing/')
```

My models :

```
class Tube(models.Model):
    tube_number = models.IntegerField()
    name_ing = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=255, default='')
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('tube_ing:tube_detail', kwargs={"my_id": self.id})


class Ing(models.Model):
    name_ing = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=255, default='')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tube_ing:tube_choice', kwargs={"id_ing": self.id})
```

And my url patterns :

```
path('', views.tube_view, name='tube_view'),
path('<int:my_id>/', views.tube_detail_view, name='tube_detail'),
path('ing/<int:id_ing>/', views.tube_choice, name='tube_choice'),
path('ing/tube_form/', views.tube_form, name='tube_form')
```

So I don't know what to put in my form and how to proceed to keep the tube's info.
Thanks a lot to the ones who will take some time to help me on this.

Comment: ">if their is a way to keep the tube id." Yes, in your `tube_form` function try accessing `request.session['my_id']`, the tube ID was established from the the `tube_detail_view`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realize it.
And that's enough for me to get it work.

Comment: Nice, glad that worked out! I'll post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

> if [there's] a way to keep the tube id[?]

Yes, in your `tube_form` function try accessing `request.session['my_id']`, the tube ID was established from the the `tube_detail_view`.